# Fill values into numpy array that depend non-trivially on indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

The problem: I'm trying to fill a 2D array `arr` with values where the values depend on the indices `(i, j)` in some nontrivial way. More precisely, `i` and `j` together provide a new index `k` (`i`, `j`, and `k` all have the same range), which I then use to lookup a value in some other array (i.e., `H[i,j] = values[k]`).

My initial thought was that `np.put_along_axis` could be used for this. I generated two lists `indices` and `values`, such that

```py
nrows, ncols = arr.shape
for i in range(nrows):
    arr[i, indices[i]] = values[i]
```

In principle this works fine, but when I try

```py
np.put_along_axis(arr, indices, values, axis=1)
```

I get the following error

```py
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

However, I can't make these lists into arrays because they're ragged; some rows have fewer values that need insertion than others. I am wondering if there is a way to use `np.put_along_axis`?

Comment: put_along is essentially `x[np.arange(...), indices]` with one value in indices for each row.  So `indices` should be 1d or 2d with matching number of rows.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That will help understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you probably want to use `np.indices`.

Since you didn't give an example I will use indices to calculate polar coordinates and look them up in an other picture.

First I have a picture to look up the values later

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

n = 100
func = lambda i,j: np.linalg.norm(np.array([i-n/2,j-n/2]), axis=0)
arr = np.fromfunction(func, (n,n), dtype='int')
arr = (arr < np.median(arr)).astype('int')
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Now I calculate polar coordinates on the above picture. In case you need a refresher on your calculus. This means we identify points by distance to a point and angle. I.e. if you go left/right in the below picture you go in a circle (counterclockwise/clockwise) on the above on and up and down means you go to and away from the center. In polar coordinates the disk should more or less turn into a rectangle.

```
r,phi = np.indices(arr.shape, dtype='float')
r *= 50/100
phi *= 2*np.pi/100

def polar2cartesian(r, phi):
    x = r * np.cos(phi)
    y = r * np.sin(phi)
    return(x, y)

i,j = polar2cartesian(r, phi)
i = (i+50).astype('int')
j = (j+50).astype('int')

out = np.zeros(arr.shape)
out = arr[i,j]
plt.imshow(out, cmap='gray')
plt.xlabel('phi (0 to 2pi)')
plt.ylabel('r (0 to 50)')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this did it! I used np.meshgrid, and this did exactly what I needed it to. Thanks!